# Using for loop to append div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code I have a HTML form that a user fills. They then enter a value in the field "member" and click on the button to generate additional copies of div = 'sector_prop'.
FORM part is - 
        Number of Sectors (LTE)

```
<br>                                                                   
<br>
<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">
 <br>
 <br>

 <button>Generate Sector Properties</button>
```

Here div "sector_prop" is

```
<div class="sector_prop">
<fieldset>
Primary LTE Carrier (Select lowest frequency on the site 850 for Band 5, AWS 
for Band 4 and PCS for Band 2)<br>
<br>
<select name="lte_freq1">
<option value="6">850</option>
<option value="2">AWS</option>
<option value="4">PCS</option>
</select>
<br>
</fieldset>
```

I want to append the div using a for loop. This code works perfectly well for values 1,2,3,4,5. When value of number is 6 or above the code breaks and appends more  than the needed div. I am trying to find out why this happens. Any suggestions ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
var repeat = $('.sector_prop');
var cloned = repeat.clone(true);
console.log(number);
for (i=1;i<number;i++){
    cloned.appendTo('.sector_prop');
    console.log(i);
console.log(cloned);
}


 });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
    var repeat = $('.sector_prop');
    var cloned = repeat.clone(true);
console.log(number);
 for (i=1;i<number;i++){
        cloned.appendTo('.sector_prop');
        console.log(i);
 console.log(cloned);
 }
 

    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form action="/form" method="post">

<fieldset>
<legend><b> Transport Information</b></legend>
<br>
<br>
 OAM IP:<br>
<input type="text" name="oam_ip" pattern="^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$"  required>
<br>
<br>

<fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend><b> RF Parameters</b></legend>
<br>
Number of Sectors (LTE)<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">
<br>
<br>

<button>Generate Sector Properties</button>

<br>
<br>
<fieldset>

<div class="sector_prop">
<fieldset>
Primary LTE Carrier (Select lowest frequency on the site 850 for Band 5, AWS for Band 4 and PCS for Band 2)<br>
<br>
<select name="lte_freq1">
  <option value="6">850</option>
  <option value="2">AWS</option>
  <option value="4">PCS</option>
</select>
<br>

<br>


</fieldset>
</div>

<input type="submit">
</form>
<br>
<br>
</body>
```

Comment: can you put it on plunkr or use the snippet ?

Comment: maybe `i` should be equal to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this look like what you are talking about?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
var repeat = $('fieldset');
var cloned;
//console.log(number);
for (i=1;i<number;i++){
    cloned = repeat.clone(true);
    cloned.appendTo('.sector_prop');
    //console.log(i);
    //console.log(cloned);
}


 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>                                                                   
<br>
<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">
 <br>
 <br>

 <button>Generate Sector Properties</button>
Here div "sector_prop" is

<div class="sector_prop">
<fieldset>
Primary LTE Carrier (Select lowest frequency on the site 850 for Band 5, AWS 
for Band 4 and PCS for Band 2)<br>
<br>
<select name="lte_freq1">
<option value="6">850</option>
<option value="2">AWS</option>
<option value="4">PCS</option>
</select>
<br>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it does. can you please explain the logic behind the fix.

Comment: 1) You are missing a closing div tag. 2) If you clone outside the loop, then you are not creating a new element every time. 3) if you clone the list instead of the element, then you are going to grow exponentially. Imagine this: You have this array [a], and now you want to clone it and append it to itself. You end up with [a,[a]]. Second time: [a,[a,[a,[a]]]], etc... but if you clone the first element alone, then you end up with [a,a,...,a]